# docker ps (programmatically in Java)

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I'm developing a SpringBoot proxy for database run on Docker remote image. What I do is execute a bash command and read the output.

My problem is that whenever I use a "docker ps" command - the output is null, because the exit code is 1. **Is there a way to read the output of "docker ps" programmatically?**

The project is here: https://github.com/k-wasilewski/workshop

Comment: Can you provide more context and code?

Comment: I added the link

Comment: You generally need to include the actual code in your SO questions, not just a link.  It's definitely possible to read other commands' output and parse them; better practice is to use something like the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) to list containers.  (And remember that being able to run any Docker command or talk to the API implies the ability to almost trivially root the host; be very careful with basic security concerns.)

Answer (score 0):

[Double quotes](https://github.com/k-wasilewski/workshop/blob/ccd2c8c56df437536ec749e8be0a3ade6181248d/src/main/java/com/flairstech/workshop/config/DockerProxy.java#L7) are not required.

```java
public final static String CHECK_DOCKER_PORT_AVAILABILITY_CMD = "docker ps --filter expose=5432 --format {{.Ports}}";
```